# Stripping GPS coordinates from string

Tags: jquery

I'm using [Mapbox](http://www.mapbox.com) to display a map on my web page. When a user moves a marker I want to get the new lat/lng coordinates and store them.

To get the lat/lng coordinates I'm using a function:

```
marker.getLatLng()
```

Which returns the following:

```
LatLng(51.5096, -0.20256)
```

This works OK but I would like the coordinates separated in two variables, like so:

```
var lat = 51.5096;
var lng = -0.20256;
```

How do I go about separating them in Jquery? I thought about simply removing the first occurrence of `LatLng(` and then removing the last occurrence of `)` and then splitting the string by the comma. However, this seems overkill and would like to know the preferred way to do it.

**MY WORKING FIX**

```
var latlng = marker.getLatLng();
var new_latlng = latlng.toString().split('(').pop().split(')').shift().split(',')
var marker_lat = new_latlng[0].trim();
var marker_lng = new_latlng[1].trim();
```

Comment: Why would it be overkill? `str.split('(').pop().split(')').shift().split(',')`

Comment: @adeneo, could you possibly add that as an answer. I actually used your suggestion and would be good to accept something. When I say 'overkill', I meant **my** splitting method was overkill as it was on 4 lines. Yours seemed less chunky than mine and was all on one line, so I used that. I also learned about popping and shifting, which was nice. I thought that was what I was meant to do on the dance floor.

Comment: I added what I decided to use at the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string doesn't somehow change, but stays the same, splitting it is actually not a bad idea, and by using `shift()` and `pop()` you can do it all in one line:

```
str.split('(').pop().split(')').shift().split(',')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your way wouldn't be overkill and would be perfectly normal for handling the string. I don't see a problem there. Anyway if you wanted to do something more fancy, not necessarily better, here is one solution:

```
var str = "LatLng(51.5096, -0.20256)";
eval(str); // do try... catch here

function LatLng(lat,lng){
    alert(lat);
    alert(lng);
    // do what you want with them
}
```

so to create a function LatLng and eval the string

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I think you're right about Regex and Eval being more expensive than string functions, which is why I went with Adeneo's suggestion, using Pop and Shift, all on one line.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex for this -

```
var coordArray = "LatLng(51.5096, -0.20256)".match(/LatLng\(([^,]*)\,\s([^,]*)\)/),
    lat = coordArray[1],
    long = coordArray[2];
```

Comment: Yeah! I was also thinking of that. Eval and RegExp are expensive, I guess in the end, normal string functions were the best

Comment: @hRvoed, Thanks for your efforts, both of you. I think you're right about Regex and Eval being more expensive than string functions, which is why I went with Adeneo's suggestion, using Pop and Shift, all on one line.